# How to restrict the value of an XML element using xsi:type in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

I would like to validate text values of an element based on attribute value. For example

```
<Device xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Parameter xsi:type="xsd:unsignedInt">-100</Parameter>
  <Parameter xsi:type="xsd:boolean"></Parameter>
  <Parameter>hello</Parameter>
</Device>
```

Both the above should fail. For boolean, anything shouldn't be accepted except "true" or "false" (even empty string)

My xml is much more complex with lot of `Object` and `Parameter` nodes and this is my xsd which is validating all those nodes recursively

```
    <xs:complexType name="deviceType">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element ref="Object"/>
                    <xs:element ref="Parameter"/>
            </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="objType">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element ref="Object"/>
                    <xs:element ref="Parameter"/>
            </xs:choice>
            <!-- Add all valid attributes for 'Object' type here -->
            <xs:attribute name="Id" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="Flag" use="required"/>
            <xs:anyAttribute processContents="lax"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="paramType" mixed="true">
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element ref="Object"/>
                    <xs:element ref="Parameter"/>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:attribute name="Id" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="Flag" use="required"/>
            <xs:anyAttribute processContents="lax"/>
    </xs:complexType>
```

But I'm facing this error.

```
Type 'xsd:unsignedInt' is not validly derived from the type definition, 'paramType', of element 'Parameter'.
Type 'xsd:unsignedInt' is not validly derived from the type definition, 'paramType', of element 'Parameter'.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## To use `xsi:type` in your XML document:

1. Declare the `xsi` namespace prefix, usually on the root element:

   ```
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   ```
2. Declare the `xs` (or `xsd`) namespace prefix, usually on the root element:

   ```
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   ```
3. Add any XSD type to the element you wish to constrain:

   ```
   xsi:type="xs:boolean"
   ```

These changes are made directly in your XML document.  You do not have to make any changes to your XSD.  However, ***the chosen type must be validly derived from the type provided by the XSD for the given element***.

---

### Relevant W3C References

From **[XML Schema Part 1: Structures Second Edition](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/)**...

> **[2.6.1 xsi:type](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/structures.html#xsi_type)**
>
> The [Simple Type Definition (§2.2.1.2)](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/structures.html#Simple_Type_Definition) or [Complex Type Definition
>   (§2.2.1.3)](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/structures.html#Complex_Type_Definition) used in [·validation·](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/structures.html#key-vn) of an element is usually
>   determined by reference to the appropriate schema components. An
>   element information item in an instance may, however, explicitly
>   assert its type using the attribute `xsi:type`. The value of this
>   attribute is a [·QName·](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/structures.html#gloss-QName); see [QName Interpretation (§3.15.3)](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/structures.html#src-qname)
>   for the means by which the [·QName·](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/structures.html#gloss-QName) is associated with a type
>   definition.

[...]

> **[Validation Rule: Element Locally Valid (Element)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cvc-elt)**
>
> 4.3 The [·local type definition·](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#key-ltd) must be validly derived from the [{type definition}](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#type_definition) given the union of the [{disallowed
>   substitutions}](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#e-exact) and the [{type definition}](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#type_definition)'s [{prohibited
>   substitutions}](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#ct-exact), as defined in [Type Derivation OK (Complex)
>   (§3.4.6)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cos-ct-derived-ok) (if it is a complex type definition), or given
>   {disallowed substitutions} as defined in Type Derivation OK (Simple)
>   (§3.14.6) (if it is a simple type definition).

From **[XML Schema Part 2: Datatypes Second Edition](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-2-20041028/)**...

**[3 Built-in datatypes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#built-in-datatypes)**

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. It helped a lot. Can you take a look at updated question?

Comment: Answer updated to emphasize  that the chosen type must be validly derived from the type provided by the XSD.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of how to derive ''xsd:unsignedInt" from 'paramType' of my xsd

Comment: As the error message indicates, and the diagram supports, the basic type `unsignedInt` cannot be derived from the complex type, `paramType`.  If you are able to change your XSD, I suggest that you ask a new question (making sure to include the referenced element declaration for `Parameter`) about how best to restructure your XSD to support your goal.  The answer will probably involve making sure that one of the elements of `paramType` is of type `anySimpleType` so that you can then override it with any subtype of `anySimpleType`.

Comment: Thanks. I asked a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33917943/use-datatype-directly-with-in-xml