# Use datatype directly with in XML

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I'm trying to validate below XML with the below XSD:

**XML**

```
<Device xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Parameter Id="100" Flag="100" xsi:type="xsd:unsignedInt">-100</Parameter>
</Device>
```

**XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xsd:element name="Device">
           <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                   <xsd:element name='Parameter' type='paramType' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='unbounded' />
                </xsd:sequence>        
           </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>

        <xsd:complexType name="paramType">              
                        <xsd:attribute name="Id" use="required"/>
                        <xsd:attribute name="Flag" use="required"/>
                        <xsd:anyAttribute processContents="lax"/>            
        </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

I'm facing 2 issues:

**Unable to use `xsd:unsignedInt` directly in XML with below error**

```
Type 'xsd:unsignedInt' is not validly derived from the type definition, 'paramType', of element 'Parameter'
```

**Unable to use both `xsd:type` and other non-namespaced attributes at the same time**

```
Element 'Parameter' is a simple type, so it cannot have attributes, excepting those whose namespace name is identical to 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' and whose [local name] is one of 'type', 'nil', 'schemaLocation' or 'noNamespaceSchemaLocation'. However, the attribute, 'Flag' was found.
```

How do I edit my XSD to fix these issues. My final requirement is that all the `Parameter` nodes should contain `Id` and `Flag` attributes and its value should be validated against type provided (in the actual XML itself).

Using `xsi:type` inside xsd is not an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `xsi:type` has to be derivable from the type specified in the XSD, and since `Parameter` is defined in the XSD to be complex, you'll probably want to create a child of Parameter, say `Value`, of `xsd:anySimpleType` that you can then override successfully via `xsi:type` in the XML document.

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Device xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Parameter Id="100" Flag="100">
        <Value xsi:type="xsd:unsignedInt">100</Value>
    </Parameter>
</Device>
```

### XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="Device">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name='Parameter' type='paramType' 
                     minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='unbounded' />
      </xsd:sequence>        
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:complexType name="paramType">              
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Value" type="xsd:anySimpleType"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="Id" use="required"/>
    <xsd:attribute name="Flag" use="required"/>
    <xsd:anyAttribute processContents="lax"/>
  </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I edit my XSD to fix these issues.

Assuming it means without touching the XML, then there is no way to make it work with pure XSD, considering the meaning assigned to the xsi:type attribute. xsd:unsignedInt is a simple type, your element is complex type, simple content.

IF you're allowed to use only one of the built in XSD types, then the only way is to change your XML; one way is described in Kenneth's answer.

If you can use your own type, then something similar to this will work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xtm="http://paschidev.com/schemas/metadata/xtm">
    <xsd:element name="Device">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Parameter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>     
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:complexType name="FlaggedParameter">
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="xsd:unsignedInt">
                <xsd:attribute name="Id" type="xsd:int" use="required"/>
                <xsd:attribute name="Flag" type="xsd:int" use="required"/>

            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

This sample then would work as expected:

```
<Device xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Parameter Id="100" Flag="100" xsi:type="FlaggedParameter">100</Parameter>
</Device>
```

Comment: Thanks. Both the answers are very helpful. But the other one was close to what I require