# Cannot resolve 'MyType' to a type definition for element 'Test'

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm trying to validate a XML with a given XSD. But I'm continuously getting the following error.

> cvc-elt.4.2: Cannot resolve 'MyType' to a type definition for element
> 'Test'.

**XML**

```
<notifications xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound">
  <Notification>
    <Test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="MyType">
       <Id>a2L1g000000OzM7EAK</Id>
     </Test>
  </Notification>
</notifications>
```

**XSD**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="notifications">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Notification">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Test">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Id" type="xs:string" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:anyAttribute processContents="skip"/>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type given by `xsi:type` has to be derivable from the type specified in the XSD, yet your XSD doesn't even define a `MyType` type.

Globally define a `MyType` type and make sure it's derivable from the type of the `Test` element.

### See also

- [How to restrict the value of an XML element using xsi:type in XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33808790/290085)
- [Use datatype directly with in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33917943/290085)

---

**Update per OP comment:**

> Can you kindly let me know how my XSD needs to be updated? I really don't care about this type attribute. So simply want to make the XSD validation a success. Please note that I can't change the XML structure as it's coming from an external system.

This XSD would be valid against the unchanged XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           targetNamespace="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound"
           xmlns:ob="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="notifications">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Notification">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Test" type="ob:MyType"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="MyType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Id" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:anyAttribute processContents="skip"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Note that the above XSD renders the `xsi:type` attribute in the XML redundant.  An example XSD which demonstrates use of `xsi:type` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           targetNamespace="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound"
           xmlns:ob="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="notifications">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Notification">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Test" type="ob:TestType"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="TestType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Id" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:anyAttribute processContents="skip"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="MyType">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="ob:TestType"/>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

With this second XSD, the `xsi:type` attribute in the XML causes the type of the `Test` element to change from its default of `TestType`.  Here too the effect is inconsequential, but one could expand the `MyType` to differ from `TestType`.  The constraint is that it `MyType` must still derive from `TestType`.

### See also

- [Example of extending complex types in XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50785402/290085)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you kindly let me know how my XSD needs to be updated? I really don't care about this type  attribute. So simply want to make the XSD validation a success. Please note that I can't change the XML structure as it's coming from an external system.

Comment: Answer updated to address your comment.