# xmlns, xmlns:xsi, xsi:schemaLocation, and targetNamespace?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces, xsd-validation, xml-validation

For the following XML fragment:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
```

What do the `xmlns`, `xmlns:xsi`, and `xsi:schemaLocation` attributes exactly mean? How are they related? What's the `:` for?

And there are 2 URLs in the `xsi:schemaLocation=`

1. http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0  (it happens to be the same as `xmlns` but it gives a 404 error when visiting.)
2. http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd  (this is an actual XSD doc)

If 1 doesn't exist, why still put it there?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

### **Namespace related attributes in XML and XML Schema (XSD)**

- [**`xmlns`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#ns-decl) is part of the [W3C Namespaces in XML Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/):

  > The prefix **xmlns** is used only to declare namespace bindings and
  >   is by definition bound to the namespace name
  >   http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/.

  **In your example**, it declares that `http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0` is the default namespace for the elements in your Maven project.
- [**`xmlns:xsi`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#Instance_Document_Constructions) declares a standard namespace prefix (`xsi`) for a core namespace used in XSD: `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`

  > *XML Schema: Structures* also defines several attributes for direct use
  >   in any XML documents. These attributes are in a different namespace,
  >   which has the namespace name
  >   http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance. For brevity, the text and
  >   examples in this specification use the prefix xsi: to stand for this
  >   latter namespace; in practice, any prefix can be used.

  **In your example**, it declares the conventional binding of the `xsi` namespace prefix to `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`, which properly sets up the use of the following attributes:

  - [**`xsi:type`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_type) allows an XML instance to associate element type information directly rather than through an XSD.   See [*How to restrict the value of an XML element using xsi:type in XSD?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808790/how-to-restrict-the-value-of-an-xml-element-using-xsitype-in-xsd)

    **In your example**, `xsi:type` is not used; included here for completeness regarding `xsi`.
  - [**`xsi:nil`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_nil) allows an empty element to be considered to be valid when the XSD might not otherwise have allowed it.

    **In your example**, `xsi:nil` is not used; included here for completeness regarding `xsi`.
  - [**`xsi:schemaLocation`** and **`xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#schema-loc) provide hints to the XML processor as to how to associate an XSD with an XML document.  Use `xsi:schemaLocation` when there is a namespace; use `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` when there is no namespace.

    **In your example**, there is a namespace, so you properly use `xsi:schemaLocation`, whose values are space-separated **pairs** of  ***namespace*** and ***XSD-location-URI***.  Your example uses the namespace, `http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0`, and namespaces are lexical naming constructs that ***[need not be retrivable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27614076/290085)***.  Your example also uses the XSD-location-URI, `http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd`, which is retrivable as it should be.

    If your example did not use a namespace, you would use `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation`, whose value is a single ***XSD-location-URI*** that hints to the location of the intended XSD and which should be retrievable.
- [**`targetNamespace`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xmlschema-1-20010502/#a-target_namespace) is an attribute on the `xs:schema` root
  element of an XSD which specifies the namespace of the root element
  of the XML document instances the XSD is intended to govern.  It must
  match the default or explicit namespace of those XML documents' root
  elements.

Comment: Thanks. So a single `xmlns` is used to define the default namespace for the document. Any element in the document without explicit namespace prefix will be in the default namespace. `xmlns:xxx` will define a non-default namespace, which must be explicitly prefixed to an element when using. Right?

Comment: You got it! Note also that a default namespace is not mandatory; you could instead declare a namespace prefix for `http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0` and use it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks. I understand it now.

Comment: Lots more up-votes needed, this is by far the clearest explanation of this that I have found to date.

Comment: I'm still confused about the xsi namespace.  In the example given, we declare the xsi namespace (`xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`), but do not give the xml processor its schema location.  Could the xsi namespace be omitted completely?  What would happen if no xsi namespace was declared, and the `schemaLocation` attribute was given without the xsi prefix?

Comment: @jrahhali: No.   You're missing two fundamental points about XML namespaces: (1) All used XML namespaces *must* be declared; (2) Namespaced component names are, by definition, fundamentally different component names than non-namespaced component names.  If you have further uncertainties, please ask a detailed new question as a question, not as a comment.  Thank you.

Comment: So `.xsd`'s `targetNamespace` should match its `.xml`s' `xsi` or default namespace?

Comment: @MinhNghĩa: `targetNamespace` should match the default or the explicit namespace of the root element of the governed XML document.  Don't be confused by the word *instance* in `xsi`: `xsi` does not specify the XML namespace of an XML document instance; think of it more as an administrative mechanism in XML document instances as described above in this answer's bullet points for `xsi:type`, `xsi:nil`, `xsi:schemaLocation`, and `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation`.

Answer (score 25):

`xmlns` defines default namespace, which states, that all nodes within project node and without an namespace-alias will be in `http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0` namespace by default.

`xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` defines namespace - `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`, and gives it a new alias - `xsi`

`xsi:schemaLocation` is an attribute `schemaLocation` of `"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` namespace. It contains pairs of values - namespace URI and schema location link for xsd-schema file of that namespace. It can contain many pairs of values - one xsd file for every defined namespace URI. That means link `http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd` contains xsd schema with definition of `http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0` namespace.