# simplexml_load_file not loading xml extension namespaces on gpx

Tags: php, simplexml, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to load some data in from a GPX file.

The file has been downloaded from Garmin Connect (https://connect.garmin.com) and has a few custom extensions for things like heart rate etc.  For some reason `simplexml_load_file()` is skipping the extensions and failing to register the namespaces for them.

To be clear, there are two things missing.  Most importantly the `ns3:*` elements are all missing from the output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gpx creator="Garmin Connect" version="1.1"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/11.xsd"
  xmlns:ns3="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1"
  xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns2="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3"
  >
   <metadata>
    <link href="connect.garmin.com">
      <text>Garmin Connect</text>
    </link>
    <time>2018-07-06T14:53:04.000Z</time>
  </metadata>
  <trk>
    <name>Stripped</name>
    <type>cycling</type>
    <trkseg>
      <trkpt lat="35.4119682700932025909423828125" lon="-2.3132956029832363128662109375">
        <ele>51.21000152587890625</ele>
        <time>2018-07-06T14:53:04.000Z</time>
        <extensions>
          <ns3:TrackPointExtension>
            <ns3:atemp>28.0</ns3:atemp>
            <ns3:hr>113</ns3:hr>
          </ns3:TrackPointExtension>
        </extensions>
     </trkpt>
     </trkseg>
     </trk>
</gpx>
```

Really simple code:

```
$foo = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
print_r($foo->getNamespaces());
print_r($foo);
```

Produces this:

```
Array
(
    [] => http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1
    [xsi] => http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
#### Missing namespaces here ####

)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [creator] => Garmin Connect
            [version] => 1.1
        )

    [metadata] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [link] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [href] => connect.garmin.com
                        )

                    [text] => Garmin Connect
                )

            [time] => 2018-07-06T14:53:04.000Z
        )

    [trk] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [name] => Stripped
            [type] => cycling
            [trkseg] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [trkpt] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [lat] => 35.4119682700932025909423828125
                                    [lon] => -2.3132956029832363128662109375
                                )

                            [ele] => 56.40000152587890625
                            [time] => 2018-07-06T14:53:04.000Z
                            [extensions] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
##### Missing extensions here #####
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

Comment: Using recursive=true --> print_r($foo->getNamespaces(true)); I see it returning ns3 too... But don't know if it's enough for you

Comment: I need the elements. Thanks for finding me the namespace

Comment: Sorry... so is that the answer you were looking for?

Comment: @koalaok No there's two parts `#### missing ####` the second is way more important. you will need to scroll down to see the second.

Comment: have a look at the answer at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34202967/xmlns-xmlnsxsi-xsischemalocation-and-targetnamespace   This may clarify you how namespace definition and usage is intended in XML files.

Comment: @koalaok I don't see how that helps, the XML document is well-formed AFAIK.  The problem appears to be that PHP isn't reading it, or I'm trying to access the elements in the wrong way.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: @koalaok I can and have read user manual pages. if you don't know the answer just move on.  The last two links you've put on are totally irrelevant.

Comment: @IMSoP Thanks. That looks like what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in :
http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.getnamespaces.php

> recursive
>   If specified, returns all namespaces used in parent and child nodes. Otherwise, returns only namespaces, if any, none in your case, used in root node.

Namespace ns3 is used in child nodes, you then need to specify recursive to true.
Otherwise you get only ns in XML root:

```
     $foo = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
     print_r($foo->getNamespaces(TRUE));
```