# XML/XSD error: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Document'

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

> Cannot find the declaration of element 'Document'.

I am trying to validate an XML file and I am getting the above error.  I have looked over the line it is flagging and compared it and I don't see the issue...thoughts?

```
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a complete answer, post a complete problem.  In the meantime...

***Notice that your error message doesn't even agree with your XML:***

- In your XML, your `Document` element is in the `urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03` namespace per its default namespace declaration.
- In your error message, there is no mention of `Document` being in a namespace.

**See also:**

- [How to link XML to XSD using schemaLocation or noNamespaceSchemaLocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411871/how-to-link-xml-to-xsd-using-schemalocation-or-nonamespaceschemalocation)
- [xmlns, xmlns:xsi, xsi:schemaLocation, and targetNamespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34202967/xmlns-xmlnsxsi-xsischemalocation-and-targetnamespace)
- [How to reference a local XML Schema file correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253402/how-to-reference-a-local-xml-schema-file-correctly)