# Error: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc, servlets, xsd

I cannot get rid of this error:

> cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.

I am running my web project on Tomcat 9. I have tried all the ways mentioned on stackoverflow, still unable to deal with it. I guess it has something to do with the Spring 5.

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        ">

        <bean id="HandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>
        <bean name="/welcome.html" class="com.gontuseries.hellocontroller.HelloController"/>
        <bean id="ViewResolver"
              class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
              <property name="prefix">
                <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
              </property>       
                <property name="suffix">
                <value>.jsp</value>
              </property>   
        </bean> 
</beans>
```

and below is the exception I am getting:

```
Sep 25, 2018 1:15:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet [spring-dispatcher]
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 6; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
    xmlns:schemaLocation="
```

to

```
    xsi:schemaLocation="
```

See also [xmlns, xmlns:xsi, xsi:schemaLocation, and targetNamespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34202967/290085)