# Getting Error Attribute xsi:noNamespaceschemaLocation is not allowed

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am getting this error:

> Error:(7, 50) cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'xsi:noNamespaceschemaLocation' is not allowed to appear in element 'fieldsMapper'.

My XML file is below:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<fieldsMapper xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xmlns="https://www.company.com/core"
              xsi:noNamespaceschemaLocation="http://www.company.com/core/fieldsMapper fieldsMapper.xsd"
              sourceType="java.util.Map"
              targetType="com.company.integration.demo.Transaction"
              id="identityValidationInputMapper">
    <fields>
        <field name="msg_date1" type="Date">
            <sourceField name="msg_date" type="String" inputFormat="YYYYMMDD" default="20200407"/>
        </field>

        <field name="msg[msg_date]" type="String" outputFormat="YYMMDD">
            <sourceField name="msg_date" type="Date"/>
        </field>

        <field name="msg_date2" type="Date">
            <sourceField name="msg[msg_date]" type="String" inputFormat="YYYYMMDD"/>
        </field>

        <field name="output_array[2]" type="Date">
            <sourceField name="msg_date" type="String" inputFormat="YYYYMMDD"/>
        </field>

        <field name="smh_msg_date" type="Date">
            <sourceField name="input_array[2]" type="String" inputFormat="YYYYMMDD"/>
        </field>

        <field name="msg_text" type="String">
            <value>
                <![CDATA[
                    Characters with markup
                ]]>
            </value>
        </field>

        <field name="msg_constant_text" type="String">
            <value>NAH</value>
        </field>

        <field name="order_amount">
            <groovy>
                just groovy code
            </groovy>
        </field>
    </fields>
</fieldsMapper>
```

My fieldsMapper.xsd is as below:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           targetNamespace="https://www.company.com/core" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="fieldsMapper" type="core:fieldsMapperType" xmlns:core="https://www.company.com/core"/>
  <xs:complexType name="sourceFieldType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="type" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="inputFormat" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="default" use="optional"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="fieldType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="core:sourceFieldType" name="sourceField" minOccurs="0" xmlns:core="https://www.company.com/core"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="value" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="groovy" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="type" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:boolean" name="sasDate" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="outputFormat" use="optional"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="fieldsType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="core:fieldType" name="field" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" xmlns:core="https://www.company.com/core">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>Nested/Mapped field in a Java bean or Map as target  Nested/Mapped field in a Java bean or Map as source   Indexed field as target (in an array or List)   Indexed field as source (in an array or List)</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="fieldsMapperType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="core:fieldsType" name="fields" xmlns:core="https://www.company.com/core"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="targetType"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="sourceType"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="id"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Any idea why I am getting this error? The XML file is valid and so is the XSD file. I tried changing the `elementFormDefault` to `unqualified` instead of `qualified` but it did not make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters,

```
xsi:noNamespaceschemaLocation
```

should be

```
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation
               ^
```

...but you shouldn't even be using `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` since your XML is in a namespace.  Use `xsi:schemaLocation` instead.

Change

```
xsi:noNamespaceschemaLocation="http://www.company.com/core/fieldsMapper 
                               fieldsMapper.xsd"
```

to

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.company.com/core fieldsMapper.xsd"
```

Note both `xsi:schemaLocation` and the change of the namespace to match your XML's default namespace and the `targetNamespace` of the XSD.

**See also**

- [How to link XML to XSD using schemaLocation or noNamespaceSchemaLocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35411871/290085)
- [xmlns, xmlns:xsi, xsi:schemaLocation, and targetNamespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34202967/290085)

Comment: I changed it to xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="fieldsMapper.xsd" and it seems it is working now. if I do xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.sas.com/boss/fieldsMapper fieldsMapper.xsd", I get URI is not registered.

Comment: Your XML has a namespace, so you should be using `xsi:schemaLocation` -- not sure what software is complaining about URI registration.  I'll add a few apropos Q/A links with further details.