# XML Validation Error: cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Statistics'

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

Here my XSD:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:complexType name="Statistics">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="date" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="email" type="xs:string" nillable="true"/>
                    <xs:element name="Advertisers">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:sequence>
                                            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string"/>
                                            <xs:element name="ls_revenue_usd_equivalence" type="xs:string"/>
                                            <xs:element name="revenue_eur" type="xs:string"/>
                                            <xs:element name="revenue_usd" type="xs:string"/>
                                            <xs:element name="revenue_rub" type="xs:string"/>
                                            <xs:element name="ls_leads" type="xs:string"/>
                                            <xs:element name="revenue_usd_equivalence" type="xs:string"/>
                                            <xs:element name="leads" type="xs:string"/>
                                            <xs:element name="payout_usd" type="xs:string"/>
                                            <xs:element name="payout_rub" type="xs:string"/>
                                            <xs:element name="payout_eur" type="xs:string"/>
                                            <xs:element name="payout_usd_equivalence" type="xs:string"/>
                                            <xs:element name="profit" type="xs:string"/>
                                        </xs:sequence>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="total">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="leads" type="xs:string"/>
                                <xs:element name="payout_usd" type="xs:string"/>
                                <xs:element name="payout_rub" type="xs:string"/>
                                <xs:element name="payout_eur" type="xs:string"/>
                                <xs:element name="payout_usd_equivalence" type="xs:string"/>
                                <xs:element name="profit" type="xs:string"/>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Here is my XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Statistics xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
        <item>
            <id>1</id>
            <date>16.12.2015</date>
            <name>test</name>
            <email>test</email>
            <Advertisers>
                <item>
                    <id>2</id>
                    <ls_revenue_usd_equivalence>0</ls_revenue_usd_equivalence>
                    <revenue_eur>0</revenue_eur>
                    <revenue_usd>0</revenue_usd>
                    <revenue_rub>0</revenue_rub>
                    <ls_leads>0</ls_leads>
                    <revenue_usd_equivalence>0</revenue_usd_equivalence>
                    <leads>0</leads>
                    <payout_usd>0</payout_usd>
                    <payout_rub>0</payout_rub>
                    <payout_eur>0</payout_eur>
                    <payout_usd_equivalence>0</payout_usd_equivalence>
                    <profit>0</profit>
                </item>
            </Advertisers>
            <total>
                <leads>0</leads>
                <payout_usd>0</payout_usd>
                <payout_rub>0</payout_rub>
                <payout_eur>0</payout_eur>
                <payout_usd_equivalence>0</payout_usd_equivalence>
                <profit>0</profit>
            </total>
        </item>
 </Statistics>
```

When I trying validate this XML, I get this error:

> cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Statistics'.

At first glance, all right, and namespaces matches. I do not understand what could still be a mistake. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, ***don't re-use a well-known namespace***, `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`, for something other than its intended purpose.  You're just asking for confusion, conflicts with existing XML catalogs, etc.

Second, ***`attributeFormDefault` and `elementFormDefault` do not belong in your XML but in your XSD***.

Third, as Martin Honnen mentions, your ***XSD lacks an element declaration for `Statistics`***.

Fourth, if you really can't change that XSD but want to use it, you could do one of the following:

- ***Import it into a wrapper XSD*** that does declare a `Statistics`
  element, and use *that* XSD to govern your XML.
- ***Use `xsi:type` in your XML.***   See [How to restrict the value of an
  XML element using xsi:type in XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33808790/290085)

Here's how to use `xsi:type` in your case (without recommended namespace fix applied):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Statistics xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml try.xsd"
            xmlns:tns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xsi:type="tns:Statistics">
  <item>
    <id>1</id>
    <date>16.12.2015</date>
    <name>test</name>
    <email>test</email>
    <Advertisers>
      <item>
        <id>2</id>
        <ls_revenue_usd_equivalence>0</ls_revenue_usd_equivalence>
        <revenue_eur>0</revenue_eur>
        <revenue_usd>0</revenue_usd>
        <revenue_rub>0</revenue_rub>
        <ls_leads>0</ls_leads>
        <revenue_usd_equivalence>0</revenue_usd_equivalence>
        <leads>0</leads>
        <payout_usd>0</payout_usd>
        <payout_rub>0</payout_rub>
        <payout_eur>0</payout_eur>
        <payout_usd_equivalence>0</payout_usd_equivalence>
        <profit>0</profit>
      </item>
    </Advertisers>
    <total>
      <leads>0</leads>
      <payout_usd>0</payout_usd>
      <payout_rub>0</payout_rub>
      <payout_eur>0</payout_eur>
      <payout_usd_equivalence>0</payout_usd_equivalence>
      <profit>0</profit>
    </total>
  </item>
</Statistics>
```

Comment: I would underline the point about not abusing a namespace that you don't own. A schema validator is perfectly entitled to say "Ah, the XHTML namespace; I know all about that already, I don't need to bother reading this schema".

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a complex type with `xs:complexType name="Statistics"`, but not an element of that name. You would need to define `<xs:element name="Statistics"><xs:complexType>...</xs:complexType></xs:element>`.

Comment: if I can not change xsd file - then I need to remove the <Statistics> element from xml?

Comment: If the schema defines no global elements then I don't see how you could write an instance document to be valid against the schema, other then maybe doing `<Statistics xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Statistics" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">...</Statistics>`. But that it is very unusual that a schema does not define any global elements. On the other hand, your target namespace is the XHTML namespace of the W3C, so I wonder anyway what the schema is trying to do with that namespace.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, IIRC FpML works a bit like this: it's normal practice to validate against a type defined in the instance document using xsi:type, rather than against a global element declaration.