# XML Schema validation error - missing declaration of element

Tags: xml, xsd

Following is the xsd.

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:dmb="http://hmh.mycompany.com/schema/hmh/Message"
    targetNamespace="http://hmh.mycompany.com/schema/hmh/Message"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    version="1.0">

    <xsd:complexType name="Message">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>This represents the message 
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="provider" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="product" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="status" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

And following is the xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Message xmlns="http://hmh.mycompany.com/schema/hmh/Message">
    <provider>PRODUCT</provider>
    <product></product>
    <status></status>
</Message>
```

When try to validate it using http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation, I got following error

> Line 2, 62: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 62; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Message'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close.  In addition to defining the `Message` *type*, you also have to declare the `Message` *element* itself.  You can do so by adding,

```
<xsd:element name="Message" type="dmb:Message"/>
```

to your XSD.  Then your XML will be valid against your XSD.

---

If you cannot change the XSD, then you have two other options:

1. Write a new XSD that defines the `Message` element as I show above,
   and `xsd:include` the type definition from the fixed XSD.  Use this new
   XSD to validate your XML.
2. Use `xsi:type` in the XML file.  (See
   [How to restrict the value of an XML element using xsi:type in XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808790/how-to-restrict-the-value-of-an-xml-element-using-xsitype-in-xsd))

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't change the xsd.

Comment: Answer updated to provide two options for when you cannot change the XSD.