# What is the use of XSD complexType without element reference?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm tasked with validating and interpreting and XSD Schema, this schema starts with:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://....">
<xsd:complexType name="TemplateType"> <!-- Nowhere referenced -->
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="DataType" type="DocumentDataType"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="DocumentDataType">
```

It's been too long since my last XSD task, but somewhere I would expect a `<element type="templateType">`, but this is not the case.

What is wrong here? My rusty XSD knowledge or the delivered XSD?

Comment: In your xsd:schema tag you most probably reference a schema which contains the definitions for complexType, sequence etc (i.e. http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema). Then you can use those types and define your own XML elements, like TemplateType, DataType etc.

Comment: You can also play with this on-line validator to help you in your XSD-related tasks: http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/#.WplSI4Khcy4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A complex type name (`xsd:complexType/@name`) could be

1. Used to define the type of an element (`xsd:element/@type`), as you say.
2. Used to define derived types via extension (`xsd:extension/@base`) or
   restriction (`xsd:restriction/@base`).
3. Used in XSDs that include or import this XSD.
4. Used in [XML instances via `xsi:type`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808790/how-to-restrict-the-value-of-an-xml-element-using-xsitype-in-xsd). <sub><sup>[**Credit @MichaelKay**]</sup></sub>
5. Planned for future use in the current XSD.
6. Simply be unused.

So, your `TemplateType` may serve another purpose besides the direct definition of an element type, or it may have become vestigial over the course of the evolution of the XSD.

Comment: It could also be referenced using `@xsi:type` in an instance document. There are some vocabularies/frameworks such as Fpml that make heavy use of `@xsi:type` in this way.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Ah, I forgot about `@xsi:type`; good point.  Answer updated.  Thank you!