# The prefix "xsi" for attribute "xsi:type" associated with an element type is not bound

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xml-namespaces

I wrote XSLT, but I'm getting the following error:

> The prefix `xsi` for attribute `xsi:type` associated with an element type `RemoteException` is not bound.

**My input XML is**

```
<RemoteException xsi:type='ns1:Exception' xmlns:ns1='http://errorhandling.service.e2e.de'>
     <causeClass xsi:type='xsd:string'>de.common.exception.StringLengthException</causeClass>
     <causeMessage xsi:type='xsd:string'>lfdNr has invalid length: 11 (min: 14, max: 14, content: '035593111P0')</causeMessage>
     <causeStackTrace xsi:type='xsd:string'>at)</causeStackTrace>
     <errorCode xsi:type='xsd:int'>201</errorCode>
     <message xsi:type='xsd:string'>invalid length</message>
    </RemoteException>
```

**XSLT Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl soap response ns1   xsi" 

xmlns:response="http://tempuri.org/" 

xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:ns1="http://errorhanlding.service.e2e..de" 

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <!-- Output -->
   <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">

     <xsl:if test="//RemoteException">
         <Fault_MT_Test>
            <standard>
               <faultText>
                  <xsl:value-of select="//faultstring"/>
               </faultText>
               <faultUrl>
                  <xsl:value-of select="//faultcode"/>
               </faultUrl>
            </standard>
         </Fault_MT_Test>
      </xsl:if>

   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Could you please explain to me what this error means and how to eliminate it?

Comment: The error is caused by your input, not by your XSLT.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I get this fault format always from partner , if I am not allow to do SOAP Envelope

Answer (score 3):

XML namespace prefixes such as `xsi` must be defined; otherwise, the XML is not namespace-well-formed.  It doesn't matter that you don't control the XML.  Either tell those upstream of you to fix it (it is undeniably ***broken***), or fix it yourself.

To declare `xsi`, add the following: `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`.

### See also

- [How to restrict the value of an XML element using xsi:type in XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33808790/290085)
- [xmlns, xmlns:xsi, xsi:schemaLocation, and targetNamespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34202967/290085)