# Use of XSD namespace prefix in XSD type attributes

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces, xsd-validation, xml-validation

In resources like [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xsd/xsd_string.htm) we see examples like this:

```xml
<xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
```

Where the type is given as `"xs:string"`. Does this assume that the XSD namespace is prefixed as `xs`.

For example, is it legal to open our XSD document something like?

```xml
<foo:schema xmlns:foo="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

And if we did so, would the first example become?

```xml
<foo:element name="name" type="foo:string"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Does this assume that the XSD Schema namespace is aliased (not sure if that's the right term) as `xs`.

Yes, namespace prefixes such as `xs` must be declared:

```
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

Yes, you could use `foo` rather than `xs`, but go with `xs` or `xsd` as they've become the convention and so will surprise readers the least.

---

If you're defining types directly in your XML, you'll also want to declare,

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

and use it:

```
xsi:type="xs:string"
```

See also [How to restrict the value of an XML element using xsi:type in XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33808790/290085)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I found an easier way to answer this than searching and reading. Using OxygenXML, the following is valid.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo:schema xmlns:foo="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <foo:simpleType name="newSimpleType">
        <foo:restriction base="foo:string"/>
    </foo:simpleType>
</foo:schema>
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why you'd want to use a `foo` namespace prefix for `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` rather than the more conventional `xs` or `xsd`?  When experienced devs see `base="foo:string"`, they'll tend initially to think that the type is a custom string rather than the built-in string.

Comment: i completely agree with @kjhughes. Here is a good link about predefined namespaces in MS SQL Server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/sequence-and-qnames-xquery?view=sql-server-ver15#qname

Comment: I don't want to, but I'm writing code that parses XSD and generates code from it, so I need to be, at least, thinking about edge cases instead of 'just getting the job done' with hard-coded mistakes like "xs:string"

Comment: @MatthewJamesBriggs. Understood. 

Comment: If you're using an XML parser, and you absolutely should be, then you'd have to go out of your way to develop a dependency on the particulars of the namespace prefix used.  Simply do don't do that.