# Can two xsi:type attributes exist in the same element?

Tags: xml, types, xml-attribute, xsi

Within XML there exits elements and attributes. There is a special attribute called `xsi:type`. Can an element have two xsi:type declarations? Example using Dublin Core.

Element Example

```
 <dc:date>1091</dc:date>
```

Attribute Example

```
 <dc:date xsi:type="dcterms:dateCopyrighted">2022</dc:date>
```

Question: Is the following Valid?

```
 <dc:date xsi:type="dcterms:dateCopyrighted" xsi:type:="dcterms:W3CDTF">2012-11-11</dc:date>
```

I've looked in various W3C documents and various XML books. I can't find anyone talking about two instances of `xsi:type`. My suspicion is that the second type will overwrite the first especially if the two values are in the same namespace as is provided in the question example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there cannot be two `xsi:type` attributes on the same element because XML in general prohibits any two attributes from having the same name:

> [3.1 Start-Tags, End-Tags, and Empty-Element Tags](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-starttags)
>
> **Well-formedness constraint: Unique Att Spec**
>
> An attribute name must not appear more than once in the same start-tag
> or empty-element tag.

### See also

- [How to restrict the value of an XML element using xsi:type in XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33808790/290085)