# Does xst:type change the element processed or just the type value of the data provided?

Tags: xml, xsi, xsitype

Within XML there exits elements and attributes. There is a special attribute called `xsi:type`. Can I declare an `xsi:tpye` value within the same namespace as the element in which it occurs? Example using Dublin Core.

Element Example

```
 <dcterms:dateCopyrighted>2022</dcterms:dateCopyrighted>
```

Question: Is the following Valid?

```
 <dcterms:dateCopyrighted xsi:type:="dcterms:W3CDTF">2012-11-11</dcterms:dateCopyrighted>
```

Please help me better understand what is happening in the questioned code. Is the whole declaration of the `dcterms:dateCopyrighted` being replaced by `dcterms:W3CDTF` and therefore impacting the type of the element's value, so the processing follows the rules for `dcterms:W3CDTF` or is only the only the type value of the data being being changed (rather than the actual element)? For example, lets imagine the expected value for `dcterms:dateCopyrighted`is a literal, while the type of `dcterms:W3CDTF` is a non-literal (to be clear this is not the case with these Dublin Core elements). So, in this case would the element be replaced and then the value type changed, or would the element stay the same and simply the value's type changed?

I found the type chart [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808790/how-to-restrict-the-value-of-an-xml-element-using-xsitype-in-xsd) helpful. In my specific case I am dealing with two different complexTypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of `xsi:type`, the schema processor will decide what type to validate `dcterms:dateCopyrighted` against by looking at the declaration of the element `dcterms:dateCopyrighted` in the schema. You can use `xsi:type` to nominate a more specific type for validation: this must be a type derived (by extension or restriction) from the type that would have been used otherwise.

In your question, I'm not sure what you mean by "a literal" and "a non-literal", but you can't use xsi:type to bypass the validation that would have happened anyway, you can only use it to define additional constraints that the data must satisfy.

Comment: Literals and non-literals refer to the type of data, as in does the value in turn point to something else... I understand this distinction to come from RDF documentation, but the best explication that I have found has been by Karen Coyle: http://kcoyle.blogspot.com/2008/09/literals-and-non-literals-take-2.html